# Is it possible to integrate jetpack compose compose with xml?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have done the entire project (with 3 activities)in jetpack compose. I need one activity to be done with xml and kotlin as I don't know how to do it in jetpack(I'm new to both). Is it possible to integrate the new activity with the rest of the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use both XML and Compose in the same project.
By Default, Android Studio create a xml file when you create a new Activity.
That it is all :)

Answer (score 7):

Jetpack Compose and XML view based system are interoperable.

> I need one activity to be done with xml

You can add [Android Views in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose)

A simple example :

```kotlin
AndroidView(
    viewBlock = { context ->
        val myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false)
        val text = myView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
        // do things
        myView
    },
    update = { view ->
        // update the view/trigger recomposition
    }
)
```